# getting GDI+ generic error while saving the image

Tags: c#, save, picturebox

My problems is that I can't overwrite the image I've opened recently.
So, let's imagine I'm opening the file with `openfiledialog`:

```
OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Images|*.GIF;*.TIF;*.JPG;*.BMP";
OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
      if ((OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
      {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))
                return;

           pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
      }
}
OpenFileDialog1.Dispose();
```

After I made some corrections on the picturebox (e.g. drawed something), I want to save the image (to the same file, from which I've opened the image) with `savefiledialog`.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP File|*.BMP";
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     pictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

It gives me an error (`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException`) also known as GDI+ generic error. So, it's basically an error which denies me to overwrite the file I've opened recently.

Comment: Please take care to use the proper the names of things to which you are referring. You and @myb both mean GDI+, not GDI. They are different APIs, with different rules, and it not only bothers my OCD, but also affects the accuracy of search results (if you were hoping for another acronym, try SEO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image` loaded by `Image.FromFile()` is keeping the file open.

You can `Dispose()` the image to release the resources, but I don't think the `PictureBox` would be too happy with that if it's still showing the old image.

Alternatively you could load the contents of the file in a `MemoryStream` and use `Image.FromStream()`.

Comment: And then dispose the MemoryStream object?

Comment: @EdwardAblekimov when you're done with the image you can dispose it - the point is you don't _have_ to dispose it before trying to overwrite the file, since the "image source" is now a `MemoryStream` which doesn't block the file I/O.

Comment: Downvoter, can you share why you downvoted this answer? I'd like to learn.